# How to send multi checkbox input value in php reusable forms?

Tags: php, forms, validation, checkbox

I am using the "reusableforms.com" PHP form script. The form is working well. But I got an error on multi-input checkbox values.

How can I get the multi-input checkbox values?

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="form-box">
    <label>Choose which of the following are most important to you:</label>
    <div class="multi-select">
        <div class="custom-select">
            <input type="checkbox" id="hight-rating" value="High Rating" name="important" hidden>
            <label for="hight-rating">High Rating</label>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-select">
            <input type="checkbox" id="mobile-phone-app" value="Mobile phone app" name="important" hidden>
            <label for="mobile-phone-app">Mobile phone app</label>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-select">
            <input type="checkbox" id="vendor-management" value="Vendor management" name="important" hidden>
            <label for="vendor-management">Vendor management</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**handler.php**

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    require_once './vendor/autoload.php';
    
    use FormGuide\Handlx\FormHandler;    
    
    $pp = new FormHandler(); 
    
    $validator = $pp->getValidator();
    $validator->fields(['name','email', 'phone', 'address', 'property', 'following', 'units', 'date'])->areRequired()->maxLength(50);
    $validator->field('important[]')->maxLength(5000);
    $validator->field('email')->isEmail();
    
    
    $pp->sendEmailTo('xxx@gmail.com'); // ← Your email here
    
    echo $pp->process($_POST);
?>
```

Thank you.

Comment: i) i think you should take the name "important" as "important[]" on the html to get multiple data.
ii) i am not sure about "FormHandler" tool. But maxLength is applicable for string type data, and you are getting array type there. and also for validating you can try the name as "important" or "important[index]". 
** i am not sure which tool you are using for processing the form. its just my thought looking at the code

Comment: Use the important[] in html and also in the formhandler as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get the form data with jQuery append functions.

```
$("#reused_form").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $form = $(this);

    var formdata = new FormData(this);
    
    var valuesArray = $('[name=important]:checked').map( function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get().join(", ");

    formdata.append( 'important', valuesArray );

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "form/handler.php",
        data: formdata,
        success: after_form_submitted,
        dataType: "json",
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your question you are not stating the checkboxes as arrays which you would need to:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="hight-rating" value="High Rating" name="important[]" hidden>
```

But if this does not help then it would be useful to elaborate the question a little bit more.

Answer (score 0):

use in html

```
    <input type="checkbox" id="mobile-phone-app" value="Mobile phone app" name="important[]" hidden>
```

in php you will receive data in the array so you shout use count not maxLength

```
$important = $_GET['important'];
$count = count($important);
```